# Merge whatsapp.app and whatsapp tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

[whatsapp.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whatsapp.app) - 84 questions tagged

[whatsapp](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whatsapp) - 5 questions tagged

Answer (score 2):

[whatsapp](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whatsapp) → [whatsapp.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whatsapp.app) ✓ [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Since these tags have identical meaning, merging is non-destructive.
[whatsapp](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whatsapp) was removed from 5 questions and [whatsapp.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whatsapp.app) added to 4 questions.

If you feel strongly that the app suffix should not be part of this app's tag, this can be pointed in the opposite direction without any loss of information, however the tag with the suffix was the original and more popular so the merge was performed in that direction at the moment.

In general, first-party apps have the app suffix on the tag, and third-party apps do not. Is this something which should be revisited?

Comment: it may be that ".app" is used to clarify generic sounding first party apps like Mail or Messages (that's the two I can think of right now...)

Comment: I agree that the generically-named first-party apps like [tag:messages.app] and [tag:mail.app] should have the suffix, but 3rd-party apps with less generic names shouldn't.